# Can not put gantt plot to dash

Tags: python, graph, plotly, plotly-dash

I did gantt plot on plotly. But now I would like to put it on dash with dropdown menu. As I'm new in dash,I did generate the dropdown menu, but I'm struggling to put my gannt plot on dash where my input should be value from dropdown menu, and output should be the line (graph) of selected value from dropdown menu.

I would really appreciate your helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not being careful enough with several things as imports, variable names and formatting.
First start with the **plotly** version:

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ObjectID': ['ITDM-1', 'ITDM-1', 'ITDM-1', 'ITDM-1',
                                'ITDM-10', 'ITDM-10', 'ITDM-10',
                                'ITDM-101', 'ITDM-101', 'ITDM-101'],
                   'Phase': ['phasezero', 'phaseone', 'phasetwo',
                             'phasethree', 'phasezero', 'phaseone',
                             'phasetwo', 'phasezero', 'phaseone', 'phasetwo'],
                   'StartDate': ['2016-12-1', '2017-3-22', '2017-8-21', '2017-9-21',
                                 '2016-12-1', '2016-12-5','2016-12-9', '2017-5-11',
                                 '2017-5-12', '2017-8-17'],
                   'EndDate': ['2017-5-22', '2017-8-21', '2017-9-21',  '2017-12-22',
                               '2017-2-5', '2017-4-9',  '2016-12-13', '2017-5-12',
                               '2017-8-17',  '2017-10-5']})


def gantt_fig(df):
    data = []

    for row in df.itertuples():
        data.append(dict(Task=str(row.Phase), Start=str(row.StartDate),     Finish=str(row.EndDate), Resource=str(row.ObjectID)))

    colors = ['rgb(0, 102, 204)', 'rgb(204, 0, 0)', 'rgb(0, 153, 0)']

    fig = ff.create_gantt(data, index_col='Resource', reverse_colors=True, show_colorbar=True, showgrid_x=True, title='Gantt Chart')
    fig['layout'].update( margin=dict(l=310))

    return fig


fig = gantt_fig(df)
py.iplot(fig)
```

From here you should try to translate it to **dash** (again) being careful about how you name things (compare to your code)

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

import pandas as pd


def gantt_fig(df):
    data = []

    for row in df.itertuples():
        data.append(dict(Task=str(row.Phase), Start=str(row.StartDate),
                         Finish=str(row.EndDate), Resource=str(row.ObjectID)))

    colors = ['rgb(0, 102, 204)', 'rgb(204, 0, 0)', 'rgb(0, 153, 0)']

    fig = ff.create_gantt(data, index_col='Resource',
                          reverse_colors=True, show_colorbar=True,
                          showgrid_x=True, title='Gantt Chart')
    fig['layout'].update( margin=dict(l=310))

    return fig


df = pd.DataFrame({'ObjectID': ['ITDM-1', 'ITDM-1', 'ITDM-1', 'ITDM-1',
                                'ITDM-10', 'ITDM-10', 'ITDM-10',
                                'ITDM-101', 'ITDM-101', 'ITDM-101'],
                   'Phase': ['phasezero', 'phaseone', 'phasetwo', 'phasethree',
                             'phasezero', 'phaseone', 'phasetwo', 'phasezero',
                             'phaseone', 'phasetwo'],
                   'StartDate': ['2016-12-1', '2017-3-22', '2017-8-21', '2017-9-21',
                                 '2016-12-1', '2016-12-5', '2016-12-9', '2017-5-11',
                                 '2017-5-12', '2017-8-17'],
                   'EndDate': ['2017-5-22', '2017-8-21', '2017-9-21',  '2017-12-22',
                               '2017-2-5', '2017-4-9',  '2016-12-13', '2017-5-12',
                               '2017-8-17',  '2017-10-5']})

options = df['ObjectID'].unique()


app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([html.H1('Gantt table'),
                       dcc.Dropdown(id='my-dropdown',
                                    options=[{'label': n, 'value': n}
                                             for n in options],
                                    value=options[0]),
                       dcc.Graph(id='display-selected-value')
                      ]
                     )



@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('display-selected-value', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_gantt(value):
    df2plot = df[df['ObjectID']==value].reset_index(drop=True)
    fig = gantt_fig(df2plot)
    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

As a general suggestion I will first write a function that return the `fig` you want to plot with plotly. Then moving to dash you can check that your dropdown menu works properly following [this](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/dropdown) and then add the callback for fig.